# Json layout grails respond

Tags: json, list, grails, groovy, marshalling

Currently i'm using a custom marshaller to render json:

```
        JSON.registerObjectMarshaller( PlannedEvent) { PlannedEvent pe ->
        return [
                id : pe.id,
                event : [
                    eventId  : pe.baseEvent.id,
                    subject  : pe.baseEvent.subject
                ],

                //rooms: pe.rooms   

                rooms: [
                    id : pe.rooms
                ]

        ]
    }
```

This gives the following output:

```
{"id":1,"event":{"eventId":626,"subject":"Baggeren hc (Kv2)"},"rooms":{"id":[8]}}
```

I would like to know how to set up my map so the value for rooms is a list with each index representing a separate room. Instead of keys, like "id", being set up as a list. The solution in comment gives to much information about the room, so I can't use that.
Wanted result :

```
"rooms":[{"id":8},{"id":9}]}
```

Comment: Try `rooms: pe.rooms.collect { [ id: it ] }`

Comment: it worked like so : rooms : pe.rooms.collect{ Room room -> [id: room.id]}

Answer (score 0):

If i am correct for your domain modelling you have a hasMany relationship between PlannedEvent & Room .So if you want to get only the list of ROOMS as IDs from the PlannedEvent domian you need to register custom marshallar for Rooms also like :

```
 JSON.registerObjectMarshaller( Room) { Room room ->
// Map of IDs is returned from here
def returnMap = [:]
returnMap["id"] = room.id
return returnMap
}
```

And in PlannedEvent:

```
JSON.registerObjectMarshaller( PlannedEvent) { PlannedEvent pe ->
// This is also a map but the value of key rooms will contain the list of IDs of each room
def roomList = [:]
roomList["rooms"] = pe.rooms
return roomList
}
```

**And for next time please clarify your domians & also what do you want clearly.**

Comment: Thanks, do you know how I can return different results based on the request so for example: /plannedevents => gives list with no details , /plannedevents/1 => gives detail from plannedevent –